# Updating Bokeh Plot in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, bokeh

I am developing in Javascript to render a table using a DataTables (Table plug-in for jQuery). I am also using Bootstrap Multiselect (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) to filter the table. I would like to re-render my BokehJS plot everytime the table is re-drawn. I have hooked up the correct calls but I am also calling Bokeh.Plotting.show to re-render the graph. This forces me to remove the last created div to avoid multiple graphs plotted. I am new to the JS side of Bokeh and wanted to understand if there is a cleaner method to update the plot in JS?

```
    var eventFired = function ( type ) {
    //var n = $('#demo_info')[0];
    //n.innerHTML += '<div>'+type+' event - '+new Date().getTime()+'</div>';
    //n.scrollTop = n.scrollHeight;   

    var plt = Bokeh.Plotting;

    // set up some data
    var M = 25;
    var xx = [];
    var yy = [];
    var colors = [];
    var radii = [];
    for (var y = 0; y <= M; y += 4) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= M; x += 4) {
            xx.push(x * (Math.random() +0.5));
            yy.push(y * (Math.random() +0.5));
            colors.push(plt.color(50+8*x, 30+8*y, 150));
            radii.push(Math.random() * 0.4 + 1.7)
        }
    }

    // create a data source
    var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
        data: { x: xx, y: yy, radius: radii, colors: colors }
    });

    // make the plot and add some tools
    var tools = "pan,crosshair,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save";
    var p = plt.figure({ title: type+' event - '+new Date().getTime(),
                        height: 300,
                        width: 300,
                        tools: tools });

    // call the circle glyph method to add some circle glyphs
    var circles = p.circle({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" }, {
        source: source,
        radius: radii,
        fill_color: colors,
        fill_alpha: 0.6,
        line_color: null
    });

    //remove old plot on update conditions
    $('.bk-root').remove();

    // Show the plot, appending it to the end of the current
    // section of the document we are in.

    Bokeh.Plotting.show(p, document.getElementById('myplot'));
    //To Do: add in transition to improve the UI appearance
}
```

And here is the the datatable setting up the call back to the BokehJS script.

```
</script>
      $('#table').DataTable({
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                }
            } ),
            renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll( {
                tableClass: 'table'
            } )
        }
    },
    paginate: false,
    info: false,
    paging: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    dom: '<"dt-buttons">Bf<"clear">lirtp',
    "buttons": [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel' ],
  }).on( 'draw.dt',   function () { eventFired( 'Draw' ); } );
```

Lastly, is there a good method to update the plot via a transition effect to improve the appearance of the re-plotting?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out all of the components in the process in a modified use case compared to the one shown above. In my present approach I needed to utilize my source data and emit a 'change' trigger.

```
source.data.factors = [my new factor list]
source.trigger('change');
```

The new factor list based on the jQuery datatable can be obtained as followed.

```
$('mytable').DataTable().columns(0, {search: 'applied'}).data()[0]
```

Also in my use case I am working with a categorical axis. In my specific use case, my factors will dynamically change upon redraw of the graph. This can be achieved using the plot's attributes.

```
p.attributes.x_range.factors = [ my new factor list from my updated source data]
```

There is also no need to remove the old plot, and the added plus is the redraw is very fast for my simple plots.